# How to parallelize updating sums with OpenMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, critical-section

The following loop iterates over all edges of a graph, determines if the end nodes belong to the same group, and then adds the edge weight to the total edge weight of that group.

```
// TODO: parallel
FORALL_EDGES_BEGIN((*G)) {
    node u = EDGE_SOURCE;
    node v = EDGE_DEST;
    cluster c = zeta[u];
    cluster d = zeta[v];
    if (c == d) {
        // TODO: critical section
        intraEdgeWeight[c] += G->weight(u, v);
    } // else ignore edge
} FORALL_EDGES_END();
```

I would like to parallelize it with **OpenMP**. I think that the code in the if statement is a critical section that might lead to a race condition and wrong results if threads are interrupted in the middle of it (correct?).

If the `+=` operation could be made atomically, I believe that the problem is solved (correct?). However, I've [looked up](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#Atomicity) the `atomic` directive and there it states that:

> Unfortunately, the atomicity setting can only be specified to simple
>   expressions that usually can be compiled into a single processor
>   opcode, such as increments, decrements, xors and the such. For
>   example, it cannot include function calls, array indexing, overloaded
>   operators, non-POD types, or multiple statements.

What should I use to parallelize this loop correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the accepted syntax for `atomic update` is:

> *x*++;
>
> *x*--;
>
> ++*x*;
>
> --*x*;
>
> *x* binop= *expr*;
>
> *x* = *x* binop *expr*;

where *x* is a scalar *l-value* expression and *expr* is any expression, including function calls, with the only restriction being that it must be of scalar type. The compiler would take care to store the intermediate result in a temporary variable.

Sometimes it's better to consult the standards documents instead of reading tutorials on the Internet. Observe the OpenMP 3.1 standard Expample A.22.1c:

```
float work1(int i)
{
  return 1.0 * i;
}
...
#pragma omp atomic update
x[index[i]] += work1(i);
```

Comment: @cls, on the contrary, _x_ in this case is a scalar _l-value_ expression. `x[i]` is also a scalar l-value expression, so it is perfectly acceptable. After all, atomic `x[i] += ...` translates to: compute the address of `x[i]`, issue locked addition to that memory address.

Comment: Thanks. With `omp atomic update`, the code actually runs faster in parallel than in serial for 10^6 edges. With `omp critical` it runs slower.

Comment: Quite simple: on x86 `atomic update` + `+=` = `lock addl addr,value` and `critical` = `call _omp_critical_acquire; addl addr,value; call _omp_critical_release`.

Answer (score 1):

I also think your if block is a critical section, you should not write a vector from multiple threads without serializing the writes. You can use `#pragma omp critical` to restrict the execution of the += in your if block to a single thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the expression in two parts: the function call that assigns the result into a temporary, and the addition of that temporary to the accumulator. In that case, the second expression will be simple enough to use `omp atomic`, assuming that the addition itself is not a complex overloaded operator for a custom type. Of course you can only do that in case `G->weight(u,v)` is a thread-safe call, otherwise you have to use `omp critical` or a mutex.

Comment: But in this case, addition involves an (overloaded) index operator `intraEdgeWeight[c] += tmp` - is this supported by `omp atomic`?

Comment: As far as I understand, the OpenMP specification does not allow that. But again, if the operator returns an lvalue reference to something of a type supported by `omp atomic`, why not splitting that expression with the help of another temporary?

Comment: I don't understand how one can avoid using the `[]` operator within the `atomic` section. Could you show me the code for what you mean?

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov, the OpenMP standard only requires that the LHS is a scalar l-value and doesn't restrict it in any other way. I have just tried this with an overloaded `operator []` and it works as expected.